# Share variables between background page and extension page without chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to share variables between background page and the others pages of my extension, but without using chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().

Something is wrong in my code because console logs

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running windows.update: No window with id: 0

**manifest**

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "/shared/utils.js",
        "/background/background.js"            
    ],
     "persistent": false
},
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
   originalTabUrl = tab.url;
   originalTabId = tab.id;
   originalWindowId = tab.windowId;
   var panelUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL("extension/views/main_panel.html");
   chrome.windows.create({
       url: panelUrl,
       type: 'panel',
       width: 600,
       height: 520
   }, function (window) {
       extensionWindowId = window.id;
   });
});
```

**utils.js**

```
var extensionWindowId = 0;
var originalWindowId = 0;
var originalTabUrl = 0;
var originalTabId = 0;

function updateTab(tabId, url) {
    chrome.windows.update(originalWindowId, {
        focused: true
    });
});
```

So with this code, originalWindowId is not assigned when I open the extension.

Comment: Variables can't be shared across contexts that way because the callback still runs in the initial context, not in the context of the created window. You can use messaging instead.

Comment: Ok. So I think I don't understand the concept behind all that ... First, I saw on a post that extension's page is a background's page. Then I saw that to access background's variable I should use getBackgroundPage(). That was working perfect, but you told me that 's bad behavior and it's better to put a shared file between background and popup. I did it, but that's not working as expected. Then now you tell me to use messaging ... I'm totally lost ... Can you explain the right way ?

Comment: IIRC you were attaching listeners inside the background page from another page, which is a different use case. You can share the variables by accessing getBackgroundPage(), although that could be a bad pattern too since it prevents you from using a non-persistent event page so ideally you should store the state in chrome.storage.local and use it to persist the state, otherwise use messaging for volatile data. Anyway, when you run util.js in two different contexts, the variables defined in util.js will belong to the context where util.js is loaded, the variables won't be magically shared.

Comment: Another trick is to pass the params in the URL e.g. `panelUrl + '?tabId=' + tabId` then in your new page you can access it using location.search, for example.

Comment: Ok, I understand the point for utils.js, the 2 different contexts and the magic :) But what do you mean by "non-persistent event page" ? I think I don't want this because I'm building an extension that runs only for special pages choosen by the user, then the user closes the extension when he has finished. So I understand your "persistent event page" to live from the moment the user opens chrome until he closes it. Am I wrong ? On the other hand, I need to keep some vars like window id, so what is the best way to store and access them ? In background with getBackgroundPage() access ?

Comment: You use `"persistent": false` in manifest.json which means the background page unloads after 5 seconds of inactivity, consequently its variables are lost. You can save the state in chrome.storage.local.

Comment: Ok, I will try that ! Thank you again and again and again :)